# "food" or "the food"? which woulod be right?

Tags: articles

I found it rather difficult to control heat and make sure food does not get overcooked.

I just started to learn English so please explain as detailed as possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a general reference to your everyday circumstances, **the** would not fit, for you would not be discussing a particular food. You might, however, want to refer to **the heat** since cooktops are implied by the existence of kitchens and homes in general.

I will also respond to this version:

> I was asked to make lunch for my sister. I thought I could do it, but I found it rather difficult to control heat and make sure food did not get overcooked.

Here, you are referring to a specific meal. The word **lunch** implies food preparation enough that you may consider **heat** and **food** implied by the context. Thgus the following would make the most sense:

> I was asked to make lunch for my sister. I thought I could do it, but I found it rather difficult to control **the heat** and make sure **the food** did not get overcooked.

To keep your verb tenses consistent, write **did not get overcooked**. All of these events took place in the completed past, so keep all the verbs in the simple past tense.

Comment: "I was asked to make lunch for my sister. I thought I could do it, but  (I found it rather difficult to control heat and make sure food did not get overcooked.) "            In this situation, should I use "the" or not?            And also thanks for the verb tense thing.

Comment: @user10219414 if you are talking about a specific occasion when you made lunch for your sister, and it was specific food that you were preparing, That means **the** is essential.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney what makes you think that this is a general reference to food? It sounds to me to be pretty specific.

Comment: @JavaLatte, without context, I genuinely believed it was a discussion of OP's habitual conditions. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney best to ask before answering.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be talking about a specific situation that occurred in the past. If this was, for example, when you were talking about "The meal that I cooked for you yesterday", then "the" would be needed.

> When I cooked for you yesterday, I found it hard to control the heat and make sure that the food didn't get overcooked.

If you are talking about your general skill then you might not need "the".

> I always find hard to control the heat and so I overcook food all the time.

But with the given phrasing, it is much likelier that you are talking about a specific event, which is understood by the listener, and so you need "the".